# Cisco 1941 router default credentials not working

Tags: router

I have a brand new 1941 router that is supposedly still running the cisco default login credentials (cisco/cisco) however I am getting login invalid. There have only been 2 people in contact with this router, the sys admin and myself and the former insists he did not change the login credentials. I have found a lot of information regarding resetting priv exec mode and the like however I cannot find anything that shows me how to reset the login credentials.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Was actually able to use the priv exec process to reset the login username and password, even though Cisco's documentation does not mention it.

Comment: For starters, the "default" is no configuration, which means *no passwords*. Second, Cisco docs do mention it ("password recovery")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the reference may can be usefull
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-123-mainline/46509-factory-default.html

Enter rommon mode :

```
Reload,
Ctrl+break
confreg 0x2142
Reset
```

Login again (cisco/cisco)

```
Conf t
Config-register 0x2102
Do wr
Reload
```

Answer (score 1):

You guys probably missed something. Cisco CP must be installed on your device, so this feature requires you change the username and password (cisco/cisco) the first time you log into your router, if not, you won't be able to log in again after you have logged off.